# How do I access the location permission settings of my react-native expo app?

Tags: react-native, expo

I am aware that we can access certain android settings using `IntentLauncherAndroid`

My current code is as follows:

```
import { IntentLauncherAndroid as IntentLauncher } from 'expo';

// onClick function to access app's permission settings
onPressButton = () => {
  IntentLauncher.startActivityAsync(IntentLauncher.ACTION_SETTINGS)
}
```

Though for now the button opens only the general settings of the phone right now.

Answer (score 0):

This code should be what you want, you can use the intent Promise to know when the user is coming back from the intent action (https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/intent-launcher/#returns)

```
import { IntentLauncherAndroid as IntentLauncher } from 'expo';

// onClick function to access app's permission settings
onPressButton = async () => {
  const intent = await IntentLauncher.startActivityAsync(
    IntentLauncher.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS
  )
}
```

Comment: Please give a brief explanation for the code you posted.

Comment: For sure! is it better?